# what is the behavior of (.)+ in a regex?

Tags: regex, perl

We just found a bug in some code where the programmer had used the equivalent of `(.)+` when they should have used `(.+)`. An easy enough fix, but we're unable to explain the behavior of `(.)+`. Can anyone explain why this matches "e", the last letter, and not "b", the first letter after the "a" in the regex? How would you explicate `(.)+`?

```
my $s = 'abcde';

if ($s =~ m{ a (.)+  }x ){
    print "s '$s' matched '$1'\n";
}else{
    print "total match fail\n";
}

__END__
output:
s 'abcde' matched 'e'
```

Comment: I believe the reason behind this is because it keeps matching until it fails to match the pattern. At which point it's the last matched character that's in the capture group.

Comment: Try adding `use re 'debug';` to the top of your code. That's good for tracking what's going on.

Comment: I like the explanation in [Repeating a Capturing Group vs. Capturing a Repeated Group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html).

Comment: @Sobrique (oops, deleted by accident) That was my first impulse but it's not very enlightening in this case, even if you already know what's going on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a huge difference between `(.)+` and `(.+)` but only in terms of what is captured, not what is matched.

`(.)+` looks for one or more *instances* of a single character and captures the last of these.

`(.+)` looks for one or more single characters and captures all of them at once.

Comment: I don't know how documented/safe `(.)+` is. I'd use `(.).*`.

Comment: @ikegami Should not it be  `.*(.)`?

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip, ack! yes, I meant `.*(.)`

Comment: "captures the last of these", yes, that's the conclusion we reached too.